# NodeJs Restful API not returning param id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a restful API using nodejs/express/mongodb. Im trying to implement SMS verification so a user will be able to receive a code via sms to verify there account.

I am having trouble returning the req.params.id from this route url.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/account/123/sms/
```

routes

```
app.use('/api/account', require('./app/routes/account.route'));
app.use('/api/account/:id/sms', require('./app/routes/sms.route'));
```

account.route

```
'use strict';

var express    = require('express');
var router     = express.Router();
var controller = require('../controllers/account.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.get('/', controller.index.bind(controller));
router.get('/:id', controller.show.bind(controller));
router.post('/', controller.store.bind(controller));
router.put('/:id', controller.update.bind(controller));
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy.bind(controller));

module.exports = router;
```

sms.route

```
'use strict';

var express    = require('express');
var router     = express.Router();
var controller = require('../controllers/sms.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.post('/', controller.store);

module.exports = router;
```

sms.controller

```
'use strict';

var User   = require('../models/user.model');
var Token  = require('../models/token.model');
var config = require('../../config/app');
var SMS = require('../../modules/sms');

class SmsController {

    store(req, res) {

        return res.json(req.params.id);

    }
}

module.exports = SmsController;
```

Im using postman to try and hit that endpoint(url). I am expecting it to return the 123 account id, but its returning nothing/empty/blank.

Comment: postman with a post request? put? get? I don't see a route handling GET `/api/account/:id/sms`

Comment: Search SO for [`mergeParams`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.router).

Comment: @Kevin B yeah its a post request with a route parameter. You can see the route in my sms.route

Comment: @robertklep "Search SO" what do this mean?

Comment: I dont know why this question was down voted i gave all the detail i knew.

Answer (score 0):

thank you to @robertklept comment about merging params, i didint know you could this before, i managed to solve it after searching express merging params

So basically i needed to nest my sms router inside my account router. Then set the optional value of mergeparams when defining my sms router.

routes

```
module.exports = function(app){

    app.use('/api/account', require('./app/routes/account.route'));

};
```

account.route

```
'use strict';

var express    = require('express');
var router     = express.Router();
var controller = require('../controllers/account.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.get('/', controller.index.bind(controller));
router.get('/:id', controller.show.bind(controller));
router.post('/', controller.store.bind(controller));
router.put('/:id', controller.update.bind(controller));
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy.bind(controller));

router.use('/:id/sms', require('./sms.route'));

module.exports = router;
```

sms.route

```
'use strict';
var express    = require('express');
var router     = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
var controller = require('../controllers/sms.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.post('/', controller.store);

module.exports = router;
```